# Finding max sum with operation limit

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sum, max

As an input i'm given an array of integers (all positive).
Also as an input i`m given a number of "actions". The goal is to find max possible sum of array elements with given number of actions.
As an "action" i can either:

1. Add current element to sum
2. Move to the next element

We are starting at 0 position in array. Each element could be added only once.
Limitation are:

1. 2 < array.Length < 20
2. 0 < number of "actions" < 20

It seems to me that this limitations essentially not important. Its possible to find each combination of "actions", but in this case complexity would be like 2^"actions" and this is bad...))

**Examples**:

array = **[1, 4, 2]**, **3 actions**. Output should be 5. In this case we added zero element, moved to first element, added first element.

array = **[7, 8, 9]**, **2 actions**. Output should be 8. In this case we moved to the first element, then added first element.

Could anyone please explain me the algorithm to solve this problem? Or at least the direction in which i shoudl try to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like dynamic programming to me.

Comment: Well, i thought that also, but still cant figure out how to do that

Comment: "Move to the next statement," reminds me of a Turing machine.

Comment: what is the output criteria?

Comment: Thanks @GirthyLampost, for some reason totally missed the goal. Edited the text, also will duplicate here:

"The goal is to find max possible sum of array elements with given number of actions"

Comment: @AntonyMikhaylov well i mean u can bruteforce it but the time complexity would be really bad

Comment: just a question. in ur first example output with [1, 4, 2]. u have 3 actions. if the number of actions equal the length of the array wouldnt u just add every element as long as its positive?

Comment: or maybe im misunderstanding how u defined action

Comment: @AntonyMikhaylov https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another DP solution using memoization. The idea is to represent the state by a pair of integers `(current_index, actions_left)` and map it to the maximum sum when starting from the `current_index`, assuming `actions_left` is the upper bound on actions we are allowed to take:

```
from functools import lru_cache

def best_sum(arr, num_actions):
  'get best sum from arr given a budget of actions limited to num_actions'

  @lru_cache(None)
  def dp(idx, num_actions_):
    'return best sum starting at idx (inclusive)'
    'with number of actions = num_actions_ available'
    # return zero if out of list elements or actions
    if idx >= len(arr) or num_actions_ <= 0:
      return 0
    # otherwise, decide if we should include current element or not
    return max(
        # if we include element at idx
        # we spend two actions: one to include the element and one to move 
        # to the next element
        dp(idx + 1, num_actions_ - 2) + arr[idx],
        # if we do not include element at idx
        # we spend one action to move to the next element
        dp(idx + 1, num_actions_ - 1)
        )
  
  return dp(0, num_actions)
```

I am using Python 3.7.12.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 100]
actions = 5
```

In example like above, you just have to keep moving right and finally pickup the 100. At the beginning of the array we never know what values we are going to see further. So, this can't be greedy.

You have two actions and you have to try out both because you don't know which to apply when.

Below is a python code. If not familiar treat as pseudocode or feel free to convert to language of your choice. We recursively try both actions until we run out of actions or we reach the end of the input array.

```
def getMaxSum(current_index, actions_left, current_sum):
    nonlocal max_sum
    if actions_left == 0 or current_index == len(array):
        max_sum = max(max_sum, current_sum)
        return 

    if actions_left == 1:
        #Add current element to sum
        getMaxSum(current_index, actions_left - 1, current_sum + array[current_index])
    else:
        #Add current element to sum and Move to the next element
        getMaxSum(current_index + 1, actions_left - 2, current_sum + array[current_index])

    #Move to the next element
    getMaxSum(current_index + 1, actions_left - 1, current_sum)
    
array = [7, 8, 9]
actions = 2
max_sum = 0

getMaxSum(0, actions, 0)
print(max_sum)
```

You will realize that there can be overlapping sub-problems here and we can avoid those repetitive computations by memoizing/caching the results to the sub-problems. I leave that task to you as an exercise. Basically, this is Dynamic Programming problem.

Hope it helped. Post in comments if any doubts.